# OpenXML SDK: get presentation shape location

Tags: c#, powerpoint, openxml, openxml-sdk

How does one accuire the location and size of shapes on the slide of PowerPoint presentation?

I'm able to accuire it from `Transform2D` property of title slide (the very first), but every other slide's `Transform2D` is `null`.

Checked the XML's for some default layout data positions - I've not been able to find anything. Only for that first slide.

While writing the post, checked one more thing. Dragged shapes a little bit. Then `Transform2D` property has value.

So question is: how does PP know what locations should shapes use if there's no data of that in XMLs? Or am I missing / misusing something?

Source:

```
private static ObjectPositionProperties GetShapePositionProperties(Presentation.ShapeProperties sp)
{
    if (sp == null || sp.Transform2D == null) return null;
    return new ObjectPositionProperties
    {
        // parse Emu values to Pixels
    };
}

private void DoStuff()
{
    // doc open, some parsing
    foreach (var s in slideShapes)
    {
        var spp = GetShapePositionProperties(s.ShapeProperties); // s is Shape located on the slide
    }
    // ....
}
```

Comment: try Tranform instead of Transform2D Graphic items like table will be transformed using Tranform . In transform u get the same Cx and Cy

Comment: There's no `Transform` property in `Presentation.Shape` object, only `Transport2D`.